# How to update categorical index to used categories in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a `DataFrame` with a categorical index and I remove all the rows from one category, the `CategoricalIndex` does not update with the only present categories and this causes problems when performing `pd.merge_asof`.

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
info = {"category":["food", "drink", "kebab"],
        "price":[1, 2, 100000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(info)
df = df.astype({"category":"category",
                               "price":"int32"})
df = df[df["category"] != "kebab"]
print(df["category"].unique())
print(df["category"].cat.categories)
```

Result of above:

```
['food', 'drink']
Categories (2, object): ['food', 'drink']
Index(['drink', 'food', 'kebab'], dtype='object')
```

As you can see "kebab" category is not present anymore, however categorical index still saves it as a category, how can I delete the unused categories from the categorical index?

Comment: Depending on your version of pandas: `df['category'].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)` [pd.Series.cat.categories.remove_unsued_categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command will solve the problem, if you add it after the selection of `!="kabab"`:

```
df["category"].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is shorter and more concise, but this may also work for your needs. The input to delete needs to be an index or boolean array.

```py
df["category"].cat.categories.delete(df["category"].cat.categories=='kebab')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem doing this, @ESDARII gave the idea:

```
df["category"]  = df["category"].cat.remove_unused_categories()
```